# Add static method to class takes array Athletes as argument and returns total nums of medals won by all

Tags: java, arrays, loops, arguments

i already have the athelete class and i just dont know how to go about the rest of the problem ive been trying to do things that havent work at all but heres what i have for now. im still a beginner this is my first semester taking java so i may not understand some of the things you guys will add so if u can please explain. 
This is what they are asking for me to do.
Add a static method to the class which takes an array of Athletes as its argument, and returns the total number of medals won by all athletes stored in the array. test in method.

```
package homework;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Athlete {
private String name;    // the name of the athlete
private String sport;   // the sport the athlete does
private int numMedals;  // the number of medals that the athlete has won


// constructor
public Athlete(String n, String s, int num) {
    name = n;
    sport = s;
    numMedals = num;
}

// getters and setters for all instance variables
// (also called accessors and mutators)
public String getName() {
    return name;
}


public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


public String getSport() {
    return sport;
}


public void setSport(String sport) {
    this.sport = sport;
}


public int getNumMedals() {
    return numMedals;
}


public void setNumMedals(int numMedals) {
    this.numMedals = numMedals;
}

/*  Returns a String with information about the athlete.
 */
public String toString() {
    return name + " does " + sport + " and has won " + numMedals + " medal(s).";
}

public static void AthMedals(int[][]numMedals){

    for(int i = 0; i < numMedals.length;i++){
        int total = 0;

        for(int j = 0; j < numMedals.length; i++);
        total = numMedals.getNumMedals();



    }



public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Athlete SA = new Athlete("Socrates","Baseball",5);
    Athlete CC = new Athlete("Cesar","Baseball",3);
    Athlete JA = new Athlete("Juan","Soccer",2);
    System.out.println(SA);
    System.out.println(CC);
    System.out.println(JA);
    System.out.println("SA has " +SA.getNumMedals()+ " medals.");




}
```

}
}

Comment: can someone help me now declare it in my main method ?

Answer (score 0):

The assignment is to write a method like

```
public static int sumOfAllMedals(Athlete[] all)
```

which returns `all[0].numMedals + all[1].numMedals + ... + all[n].numMedals`.

I assume `AthMedals` is your attempt at doing this, but it's in fact only consuming processing power while not doing anything.

I'm not gonna do your homework for you, but here's a hint:

```
public static int sumOfAllMedals(Athlete[] all)
{
    int total = 0;
    // For every Athlete in `all`, add the number of medals (s)he's won
    // Should be four lines at most ;)
    return total;
}
```

Comment: so i woud have to add :  for(int i=0;i < all.length;i++) {             
            total += all.numMedals;
        }

        return total;

Answer (score 0):

The static method have to iterate the array and add each medals to a final return variable.

```
static public int totalMedals(Athlete[] athelte) {
        int totalMedals = 0;

        for(int i=0;i<athelte.length;i++) {             
            totalMedals += athelte[i].numMedals;
        }

        return totalMeadls; 
}
```

Comment: the totalMedals += athlete.numMedals is giving me an error message telling me to switch it to length when we both know that isnt going to work atleast i think

Comment: so to call it on the main how do i do that would i do system.out.println(medals(Athlete[i]All));

Comment: to call Static methods you have to do this --> Class.StaticMethod(array)
Athlete.totalMedals(athelte);